# Borrar datos de 2 tablas MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

necesito borrar datos de dos tablas siempre que sean más antiguos de una fecha dada. Las tablas son las siguientes:

**Tabla: reserva**

```
| id | contrato_id | fecha | ...
```

**Tabla: contrato**

```
| id | tipo | precio_total | ...
```

Están relacionadas mediante la ID de contrato: en la tabla reserva (contrato_id) y en la tabla contrato (id).

La consulta que tengo hasta ahora es:

```
DELETE * FROM reserva as s INNER JOIN contrato as c ON s.contrato_id=c.id WHERE s.fecha < "'. $fecha_limite .'";
```

El problema es que ambas tablas no tienen el mismo número de registros y esta consulta no me sirve, solo me borra registros si tienen contrato hecho. Pero puede darse el caso de que haya reservas sin contrato_id porque aún no ha sido creado. ¿Cómo puedo resolverlo?

Comment: no estoy 100% seguro pero podrias probar esto:  `DELETE s, c FROM reserva as s 
LEFT JOIN contrato as c ON s.contrato_id=c.id 
WHERE s.fecha < "'. $fecha_limite .'";`

Comment: Y por qué no haces dos `DELETE` distintos?, ya que si tienes reservas sin contrato quiere decir que no es una `FOREIGN KEY`, con lo cual qué borres primero debería dar igual.

Comment: Gracias por vuestras respuestas. Si, lo he pensado, pero no la fecha solo está en la tabla reservas y para borrar en la tabla contrato necesito saber la id de cada contrato... No sé cómo plantear esto

Comment: Creo que con LEFT JOIN se soluciona el problema @LeonardoCabré, gracias por tu ayuda. Voy a comprobarlo pero al menos el número de registros es distinto a mi consulta. Mil gracias!

Comment: La respuesta de enrique manzano es la más apropiada. Igual, queda la duda de por qué la etiqueta php en tu pregunta si no hay ningún código PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que esto debería funcionar, ya que la pregunta tiene la etiqueta de php, lo he hecho en php

**php**

```
$conection = /*(conexion en este ejemplo mysqli)*/;
$sql_select = "SELECT id_contrato FROM reserva WHERE fecha < '".$fecha."'";
$result = $conection->query($sql);
$ids= "";
if($result){
//guardamos las id de los contratos que tengan reservas que hayan vencido
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
        $ids .= $row[0].", "; 
    // si las id se guardan como varchar o similar $ids .= "'".$row[0]."', ";
    }
    //le quitamos la ultima coma y espacio
    $ids = substr($ids,0,-2);
    $sql_DELETE_Reservas = "DELETE FROM reserva where fecha < '".$fecha."'";
    $result2 = $conection->query($sql_DELETE_Reservas);
    if($result2){
        $sql_DELETE_contratos = "DELETE FROM contrato WHERE id IN (".$ids.")";
        $result_Final = $conection->query($sql_DELETE_contratos);
        //Si quiere, comprobar que funciona
        if($result_Final){
            echo "EUREKA!!";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Primero: hay que tener en cuenta que no se puede hacer una eliminación de las dos tablas si depende de la fecha de la reserva. (si dependiera del contrato_id, con la llave foranea y con eliminación en casacada, si se pudiera eliminar las dos tablas al mismo tiempo)

Segundo: como es posible que existan registros mayores o iguales a fecha_limite, entonces debes primero eliminar las reservas menores a la fecha límite y después validar que si un contrato no tiene reservas entonces eliminar el contrato.

Éste diagrama describe como debes hacer esta eliminación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]